# editing Visual Studio snippets

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I'd like to edit VS Community code snippets because I don't like VS's formatting or how to call that. Anyway, I tried Snippet Designer extension but it is only for creating new ones. Is there some way to edit VS Community code snippets?

Comment: I haven't really used Visual Studio much lately, but isn't the formatting and code-style pretty configurable these days?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, it is configurable, they also now have clang-format available out of box. But at the end it is still worthless.